# Secure app for managing and synchronization health data, PHR

Tags: health

I am looking for some kind of password manager for my health data. This "health manager" should offer the possibility of structured input of health data such as blood values, vaccinations, medication, symptoms and more. The data should only be encrypted and decrypted locally. The provider of this application should not have access to any of my data, it should only handle the synchronization of encrypted data between devices. I come from Germany where all health insurance companies (Krankenkassen) are obliged to provide an app like this. Unfortunately, all the apps I tested so far are very poorly designed. Also, the health insurance companies have access to the patient data. Does anyone know of such an app that works independently of health insurance companies and does not have access to patient data?

Comment: I'm from the US, other than Google Fit / Samsung Health (which I don't consider secure) I don't know of any. Following this question in hopes you'll get answers.